# Не устанавливается атрибут checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Почему не хочет устанавливаться атрибут `checked` при выборе чекбокса?

В результате не работает отображение дополнительного контента при выборе чекбокса:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#public").change(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
      $('#hide').fadeIn().show();
      return;
    } else {
      $('#hide').fadeOut(300);
    }

  });
})
```

```css
.ajax_form.af_example {  width: 100%;}
.control-group {  margin: 10px 0;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Заполните форму</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" name="public" id="public">Включить дополнительную опцию

<div id="hide" style="display:none;">
  Описание дополнительной опции
</div>
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, _конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код_ для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, полный, воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: В качестве наказания за данный мной поспешный неправильный ответ, исправил вопрос: перенёс код из внешнего левого сайта сюда в сниппет.

Comment: Спасибо)) Впредь буду внимательнее

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Действия пользователя не меняют атрибуты html элемента, но меняют его свойства, для доступа к ним можно либо использовать метод [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#public").change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      $('#hide').fadeIn().show();
      return;
    } else {
      $('#hide').fadeOut(300);
    }

  });
})
```

```css
.ajax_form.af_example {  width: 100%;}
.control-group {  margin: 10px 0;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Заполните форму</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" name="public" id="public">Включить дополнительную опцию

<div id="hide" style="display:none;">
  Описание дополнительной опции
</div>
```

Либо напрямую проверять это свойство у `this`, так как он ссылается на элемент на который навешано событие

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#public").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#hide').fadeIn().show();
      return;
    } else {
      $('#hide').fadeOut(300);
    }

  });
})
```

```css
.ajax_form.af_example {  width: 100%;}
.control-group {  margin: 10px 0;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Заполните форму</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" name="public" id="public">Включить дополнительную опцию

<div id="hide" style="display:none;">
  Описание дополнительной опции
</div>
```

Comment: кстати [здесь описана разница](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) в версиях ниже jquery 1.6 и выше, и сам метод `.checked`. В вашем примере `return` обязателен?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, нет, `return` не обязателен, код был скопирован из ответа и просто заменено условие которое проверялось. так как `return` в данном случае никак не влияет на поток выполнения его можно как убрать, так и оставить.

Comment: А скажите, если чекбоксов несколько - как связать каждый из них со своим скрытым блоком?

Comment: @Batyabest, зависит от разметки, и что понимается под _связать_

Comment: то есть есть например 5 чекбоксов. Они расположены в столбик. По разметки после каждого чекбокса идет скрытый блок. При выборе чекбокса должен разворачиваться тот блок, который идет после этого чекбокса.Можно конечно наворотить олдинаковых кусков скрипта, с разными ID, но это не по фен-шую)) Подскажите?))

Comment: @Batyabest, если точно друг за другом: `<input type="checkbox"/><div class="hide">` Тогда можно использовать [`jquery.next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/): `$(this).next(/*здесь можно так же указать селектор, например .hide*/)` - данное выражение найдет нужный элемент после инпута, и его вы должны использовать вместо `$('#hide')`

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. А если не точно друг за другом - возможно ли как-то по индексу искать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35858/discussion-between-grundy-and-batyabest).

Comment: @Grundy а как такой спойлер как у вас в ответе сделать? Не вижу в справке такого вообще.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27134629#27134629

Answer (score 3):

Вместо `.attr()` используйте `.prop()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#public").change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      $('#hide').fadeIn().show();
      return;
    } else {
      $('#hide').fadeOut(300);
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.ajax_form.af_example {  width: 100%;}
.control-group {  margin: 10px 0;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Заполните форму</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" name="public" id="public">Включить дополнительную опцию

<div id="hide" style="display:none;">
  Описание дополнительной опции
</div>
```

Comment: я вот даже не знаю, плюсануть или пометить как не ответ :-D

Answer (score 3):

Вы пытаетесь проверить установку флажка конструкцией `$(this).attr("checked")`, которая возвращает `undefined`. Используйте для проверки `$(this).is(':checked')` (либо `$(this).prop('checked')`) и всё получится:

```
$("#public").change(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#hide').fadeIn().show();
  } else {
      $('#hide').fadeOut(300); 
  }
 });
```

Comment: таки лучше проверять свойство а не атрибут, я имел ввиду [jquery.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: @Grundy тут соглашусь. Хотя всё равно постоянно использую is() :D

Comment: ну в `is` же передается селектор, так что `prop` не во всех случаях применим когда можно использовать `is` :-)

Answer (score 1):

для проверки checked нужно использовать метод `.prop()`

```
   if ($(this).prop("checked")) {. . .
```

вот здесь подробно описана разница между attr и prop:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: стоило бы также вставить основные различия в сам ответ