# Как сделать проверку checked у input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть несколько блоков с классом .box-check , в каждом из блоков находятся несколько label с input. Мне нужно сделать проверку на checked у инпутов и если инупт отмечен, добавлять произвольный класс основному родителю (.box-check) этого инпута. Пока один из инпутов отмечен - класс существует, как только со всех инпутов выделения сняты - удалять класс у родителя.

Вот структура кода, но он почему-то не работает:

```css
.box-check {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box-check label {
  display: block;
}

.custom-class {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-check">
  <div class="bbox">
    <div class="box-check-cont">

      <div class="check">
        <label for="check-1">
                  <input id="check-1" class="element-checkbox" name="check-1" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                  <span>Масло</span>
                 </label>
        <label for="check-2">
                  <input id="check-2" class="element-checkbox" name="check-2" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                  <span>Motul</span>
                 </label>
        <label for="check-3">
                  <input id="check-3" class="element-checkbox" name="check-3" value="Rowe" type="checkbox">
                  <span>Rowe</span>
                 </label>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box-check">
  <div class="bbox">
    <div class="box-check-cont">

      <div class="check">
        <label for="check-11">
                  <input id="check-11" class="element-checkbox" name="check-11" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                  <span>Масло</span>
                 </label>
        <label for="check-22">
                  <input id="check-22" class="element-checkbox" name="check-22" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
                  <span>Motul</span>
                 </label>
        <label for="check-33">
                  <input id="check-33" class="element-checkbox" name="check-33" value="Rowe" type="checkbox">
                  <span>Rowe</span>
                 </label>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
//Проверка при загрузке документа
  var ckbox = $('.box-check input');
  if (ckbox.is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parent('.box-check').addClass('custom-class');
  } else {
    $(this).parent('.box-check').removeClass('custom-class');
  }
  //Нужно ещё сделать проверка при клике.. Возможно это можно сделать одной функцией
</script>
```

Выручите, пожалуйста.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517241/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-checked-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery

Comment: Через prop тоже не получается, мне нужно понять сам принцип, как это реализовать

Comment: и событие надо навесить на изменение состояния чекбокса `$('input').on('change', ....)`

Comment: вот пример http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494149/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82-checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли навесить событие на изменения чекбокса, чтобы убрать класс (желтый цвет), придется проверить все чекбоксы на галочки, циклом например.

**Обновлено**

```js
$(function() {

  $("input").change(function() {

    //сформируем массив галочек
    var block = $(this).closest('.check');
    var checked = block.find('input').map(function(index, elem) {
      return elem.checked;
    });

    //преобразуем в массив
    checked = checked.get();

    //проверим на вшивость
    var galki = checked.some(function(el) {
      return el;
    });

    //выполним действие
    if (galki == true) {
      $(this).closest('.box-check').addClass('custom-class');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.box-check').removeClass('custom-class');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.box-check {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box-check label {
  display: block;
}

.custom-class {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-check">
  <div class="bbox">
    <div class="box-check-cont">

      <div class="check">
        <label for="check-1">
      <input id="check-1" class="element-checkbox" name="check-1" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
      <span>Масло</span>
     </label>
        <label for="check-2">
      <input id="check-2" class="element-checkbox" name="check-2" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
      <span>Motul</span>
     </label>
        <label for="check-3">
      <input id="check-3" class="element-checkbox" name="check-3" value="Rowe" type="checkbox">
      <span>Rowe</span>
     </label>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box-check">
  <div class="bbox">
    <div class="box-check-cont">

      <div class="check">
        <label for="check-11">
      <input id="check-11" class="element-checkbox" name="check-11" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
      <span>Масло</span>
     </label>
        <label for="check-22">
      <input id="check-22" class="element-checkbox" name="check-22" value="Motul" type="checkbox">
      <span>Motul</span>
     </label>
        <label for="check-33">
      <input id="check-33" class="element-checkbox" name="check-33" value="Rowe" type="checkbox">
      <span>Rowe</span>
     </label>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но только если снять один чекбокс а остальные отмечены - класс удаляется... Нужно чтобы класс с фоном удалялся только после того, как отметки будут сняты..

Comment: @Александр ну так выше сказано, проверьте все чекбоксы, или за вас код написать?

Comment: В этом то и проблема, что не знаю как проверить все чекбоксы..

Comment: $(':checkbox:checked' ).each(function(){
    $(this).closest('.box-check').addClass('custom-class');
});

При загрузке так проверяю , а вот с проверкой на все чекбоксы пока не разберусь

Comment: @Александр начали думать правильно насчет each, обновил ответ с решением

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает.

Answer (score 0):

Выбирай:

```
this.checked
```

```
$(this).prop('checked')
```

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```